# How to get the logout message in custom login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have to create a login module for my project using Spring Security where I have overridden the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and created a custom login page.

`customLogin.jsp`:

```
<body>

    <h3>Login Here</h3>
    <font color="red">
       ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
    </font>

    <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/appLogin" method="POST">
        Enter UserName: <input type="text" name="app_username"/><br/><br/>
        Enter Password: <input type="password" name="app_password"/> <br/><br/>         
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>         
    </form>

<body>
```

And here is my configure method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers("/secure/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").
        and().formLogin().  // login configuration
            loginPage("/customLogin.jsp").
            loginProcessingUrl("/appLogin").
            usernameParameter("app_username").
            passwordParameter("app_password").
            defaultSuccessUrl("/secure/home").  
        and().logout().    // logout configuration
            logoutUrl("/appLogout"). 
            logoutSuccessUrl("/customLogin.jsp");
}
```

And where I have the logout button, I have included the following code (because Spring Security automatically enables CSRF, which automatically disables `GET` logouts):

```
 <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/appLogout" method="POST">
         <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>        
 </form>
```

When I click logout button, it redirects me to custom login page, but the default logout message is not being displayed. How can I get that message here?

Comment: If we don't write a custom login page, then when we click the logout button it redirects to the default login page and shows a message in green color " You have been logged out". I don't know how to get that behavior in custom login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form):

> An example log in page implemented with JSPs for our current configuration can be seen below:
>
> [..]
>
> ```
> <c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
> <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">       1
>   <c:if test="${param.error != null}">        2
>       <p>
>           Invalid username and password.
>       </p>
>   </c:if>
>   <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">       3
>       <p>
>           You have been logged out.
>       </p>
>   </c:if>
>   <p>
>       <label for="username">Username</label>
>       <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>  4
>   </p>
>   <p>
>       <label for="password">Password</label>
>       <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>  5
>   </p>
>   <input type="hidden"                        6
>       name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
>       value="${_csrf.token}"/>
>   <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
> </form>
> ```
>
> 1 A POST to the `/login` URL will attempt to authenticate the user
>   2 If the query parameter `error` exists, authentication was attempted and failed
>   3 If the query parameter `logout` exists, the user was successfully logged out

Also you have to add a query parameter `logout` to your `logoutSuccessUrl`.

Your modified Java configuration is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers("/secure/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").
        and().formLogin().  // login configuration
            loginPage("/customLogin.jsp").
            loginProcessingUrl("/appLogin").
            usernameParameter("app_username").
            passwordParameter("app_password").
            defaultSuccessUrl("/secure/home").  
        and().logout().    // logout configuration
            logoutUrl("/appLogout"). 
            logoutSuccessUrl("/customLogin.jsp?logout");
}
```

Comment: the issue got resolved by changing logoutSuccessUrl to `logoutSuccessUrl("/customLogin.jsp?logout");`  and checking the logout  param in the jsp. thanks a lot !.

Comment: `Also you have to add a query parameter logout to your logoutSuccessUrl.` Why?

Comment: @parsecer The question is about logout message, hence you have to know if your page is shown, because you are not logged in or you just logged out.

Comment: @dur So basically it could be anything after `?`, including, say, `?bigGreenMonkey` (and `bigGreenMonkey` is not present in any other place in code), as it is just for user's visual hint?

Comment: @parsecer: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `customLogin.jsp` page:

```
<div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">Logged out Sucessfully!</div>
```

Comment: I am not using thymeleaf. so added jstl version of the above: <c:if test="${param.logout}"> 
Logged out Sucessfully!
</c:if>

Answer (score 0):

`<!-- logout message --> <div th:if="${param.logout}"> <div class="alert alert-info">You have been logged out.</div> </div>`

You can use it.