# Login page does not show logout message how is expected

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working with `Spring Security` version `4.2.3.RELEASE`

- Use `csrf` is mandatory.

I used how reference the following for the `login.jsp` file, [5.3 Java Configuration and Form Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-form), thus I have:

```
<body>
   <spring:url var="loginUrl" value="/perform_/login"/>
   <form name="login" action="${loginUrl}" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
     <legend><spring:message code="login.legend"/></legend>
      <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
       <p class="error"><spring:message code="login.invalid"/></p>
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
       <p><spring:message code="logout.valid"/></p>
      </c:if>
      <table>
      .... fields for username and password and submit button ...
      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  </form>
```

in other `.jsp` page to logout purposes exists:

```
    <spring:url var="logoutUrl" value="/perform/logout" />
    <form id="logoutForm" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
     <a href="javascript:formSubmit()"><spring:message code="logout.title"/></a>
    </form>

    <script>
        function formSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Finally through Javaconfig for Spring Security the following exists:

```
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/perfom/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")//default
            .passwordParameter("password")//default
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .failureUrl("/perfom/login?error") //default is /login?error
            .permitAll()

        .and()

        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/perform/logout")//default is /logout
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/perfom/login?logout")//default is /login?logout
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
```

**Note**: `/perfom/login` is used in:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/message").setViewName("general/message");
    registry.addViewController("/welcome").setViewName("general/welcome");
    registry.addViewController("/perfom/login").setViewName("login/login");

}
```

When the login page is loaded and either username or password values are incorrects the same login page is loaded again and the error message appears. Therefore `<c:if test="${param.error != null}">` works fine.

The problem is when the logout *event* happens it goes to the `login.jsp` page *how is expected* but the *logout message* does not appear. But if in that moment I try to do a login with **valid** values the same `login.jsp` page is loaded again and just **then** the logout message appears.

I did a research and 'seems' correct my configuration, even according with this:

- [How to get the logout message in custom login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992760/how-to-get-the-logout-message-in-custom-login-page)

What missing configuration is need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR** You need to add another `permitAll()` call after `deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")`.

As per documentation `permitAll()` for `FormLoginConfigurer`

> Ensures the urls for failureUrl(String) as well as for the HttpSecurityBuilder, the getLoginPage and getLoginProcessingUrl are granted access to any user.

But you need to grant access to `logoutSuccessUrl` as well (to be fair access to `logoutUrl` is also needed but prerequisite for logout is that user is authenticated).

So what happens in your case is this:

1. You perform logout and get redirect to `logoutSuccessUrl` in response;
2. You dont have access to `logoutSuccessUrl` so normal process kicks in: url is saved to session and you get another redirect to login page (without parameter);
3. When you perform login you get redirect to saved `logoutSuccessUrl` and finally see your message.

Comment: Thanks, just curious, if the `permitAll()` method was added to the _Logout_, why you are referring the documentation about _Login_ (`FormLoginConfigurer`)?

Comment: To prove that it grants access to login urls exclusively and not logout, as one may think.